# Como posso usar o Firebase como base de dados em uma aplicação Django?

Tags: python, django, firebase

Acabei de criar um projeto Django e gostaria de utilizar o Firebase ao invés do sqlite como base de dados. Procurei em vários lugares mas não consegui achar em nenhum local como fazer a integração. Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: https://github.com/xtrinch/fcm-django

Comment: Cara nesse link tu vai encontrar uma resolução.Aqui no [StackOverflow em Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681362/how-to-implement-firebasedb-with-a-django-web-application)

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação do Django na parte de databases que pode ser lida em inlgês no seguinte link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/#using-a-3rd-party-database-backend:

As databases nativas são;

- PostgreSQL
- MYsql
- SQLIte

E as suportadas por terceiros são;

- SAP SQL Anywhere
- IBM DB2
- Microsoft SQL Server
- Firebird
- ODBC